# Security of data when using the qgis2web plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

While using Qgis2Web Plugin data will be save in any of cloud platform or Qgis Server ? In short usage of this plugin is safe or not ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what types of layers are in your map. If they are Shapefiles, GPKG, or database layers (PostGIS, etc), they are exported as GeoJSON into a subfolder of the map export folder. That means that if you publish the map openly, the underlying data is *not* secure. If you publish the map in a closed location, the data is part of the export, and hence will also be closed.